# Delock Adapter USB 3.0 > HDMI

Tags: usb, hdmi, monitor

I am trying to connect my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) to extra monitor with this [adapter](http://www.delock.de/produkte/G_62736/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en).

Laptop has USB 3.0 . and when i insert adapter into USB, it gets recognized in terminal with lsusb.

```
damba@damba-Inspiron-5559:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6712 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can someone help?

```
lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1d5c:2000 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.O root hub 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Carp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Carp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6712 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.O root hub
```

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal output rather than post a picture of it. Thank you!

Comment: damba@damba-Inspiron-5559:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6712 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: It's being identified as a Cmedia Audio adaptor (which in effect, it is. HAve you attempted to plug it into a USB port with an HDMI monitor alrady attached to see if you get different results? Like the ITE IT66121FN or the Fresco Logic FL2000 being recognized?

Comment: yes i try it, and the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to locate a Linux compatible driver for your device. Until some one far more motivated than I writes a driver or support for this device into the kernel, it appears that if you want to use it you are stuck with using the Operating Systems that support it which according to the product link you provided are:

• Windows 7 32-bit
• Windows 7 64-bit
• Windows 8.1 32-bit
• Windows 8.1 64-bit
• Windows 10 32-bit
• Windows 10 64-bit

Note: [NDISwrapper](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is known to make some drivers work with the Linux kernel, sadly to the best of my knowledge it requires drivers that comply to the NDIS 5.0 spec which went out with Windows XP I believe, so that isn't likely to  help you with this particular device.

Comment: Know any places where we could find lists of Linux-compatible adapters?

Comment: HDMI? No, I haven't seen such a list available for those. Since you are asking about Linux in general, you might get better results asking on our sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com/ There is a wireless adapter list [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/) and you might also find [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/supportedhardware) useful. Cheers!